# How to check if a map $X\to M(X)$ is measurable?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $M(X)$ be the set of all the finite measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.
By the Riesz representation theorem, we know that the map $M(X)\to C(X)^*$ defined as $\mu\mapsto (f\mapsto \int f\ d\mu)$ is injective and its image is the set of all bounded linear maps $F:C(X)\to \mathbf R$ which are positive, that is, those $F$ such that $Ff\geq 0$ whenever $f\geq 0$.

Equipping $C(X)^*$ with the weak* topology, we get a topology on $M(X)$ and hence a $\sigma$-algebra on $M(X)$.
On $X$ we also have the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

> **Question.** Suppose we have a map $\mu:X\to M(X)$, $x\mapsto \mu_x$.
>   Is is true that $\mu$ is a measurable map if for each $f\in C(X)$ the map $X\to \mathbf R$, $x\mapsto \int_X f\ d\mu_x$ is measurable?

Or is there some other convenient criterion to check the measurability of a map $X\to M(X)$?

Comment: Notice that the map $\pi : M(X) \to \mathbb{R}^{C(X)} $ with $ \nu \mapsto (\int_X f \, d\nu)_{f\in C(X)}$ is an embedding (where $\mathbb{R}^{C(X)}$ is equipped with the product topology). So $\mu : X \to M(X)$ is measurable if and only if $\pi \circ \mu$ is measurable. This is of course equivalent to saying that each $x \mapsto \int_X f \, d\mu_x$ is measurable for each $f \in C(X)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee "So $\mu:X\to M(X)$ is measurable if and only if $\pi\circ \mu$ is measurable." This is true when we equip $\mathbb R^{C(X)}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. But the equivalence of the measurability of $\pi\circ \mu$ and the measurability of each $x\mapsto \int_Xf\ d\mu_x$ is true when $\mathbf R^{C(X)}$ is equipped with the product $\sigma$-algebra. So I do not completely follow your comment. Can you please address this and point out any mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: I see your point. The issue is that that Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{C(X)}$ may possibly be strictly finer than the product $\sigma$-algebra for general $X$. Thank you for pointing out my mistake and sorry for the confusion. Perhaps the claim can be salvaged if $C(X)$ is separable so that we can replace $\mathbb{R}^{C(X)}$ by $\mathbb{R}^{\mathfrak{A}}$ for some countable dense subset $\mathfrak{A} \subset C(X)$, but let me think about it.

Comment: @SangchulLee I am interested in the situation when $X$ is a compact metric space and here it is known that $C(X)$ is separable. Just wanted to say this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$
$\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$
$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
$\newcommand{\mr}{\mathscr}$

WE answer the question above in the affirmative. The only difference is that I will be proving the result with $\mr P(X)$, the space of all the probability measures on $X$, instead of $M(X)$, which doesn't make much difference.

> **Lemma.**
>   Let $Z$ be a set and $f_\alpha:Z\to Z_\alpha$ be a collection of continuous maps into topological spaces $Z_\alpha$ indexed by a set $J$.
>   Endow $Z$ with the initial topology with respect to this collection.
>   Then for any measurable space $(Y, \mc Y)$, a map $\vp:Y\to Z$ is Borel measurable if and only if each composite $f_\alpha\circ \vp$ is Borel measurable.

**Proof.**
We do the less trivial direction.
Assume that each composite $f_\alpha\circ \vp$ is measurable.
Note that the collection
$$
\mc C=\bigcup_{\alpha\in J} \set{f_\alpha^{-1}(W):\ W\text{ open in } Z_\alpha}
$$
is a subbasis for the topology on $Z$.
Let $O=f_\alpha^{-1}(W)$ be an arbitrary member of $\mc C$, where $W$ is an open set in $Z_\alpha$.
But then $\vp^{-1}(O)=(f_\alpha\circ \vp)^{-1}(W)$ is a measurable subset of $Y$.
So we see that each member of $\mc C$ pulls back under $\vp$ to a measurable subset of $Y$.
Thus $\vp$ is measurable.
$\blacksquare$

> **Corollary.**
>   Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $(Y, \mc Y)$ be a measurable space.
>   Then a map $\vp:Y\to \mr P(X)$ is Borel measurable if and only if for each continuous function $f:X\to \R$ we have that the map $y\mapsto \int_X f\ d\vp_y:Y\to \R$ is Borel measurable.